# How can I prevent loss of shared folder connectivity after hibernating in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, sleep, hibernate, shared-folders

I have a shared folder on a Windows 7 64-bit machine, but my Windows 8.1 computer cannot access the folder after the Windows 7 machine goes into hibernate. Is there anyway I can reestablish that connection after powering up from hibernating or sleeping? I put the machine in sleep or hibernate to save power and state, since complete shutdown would be very inconvenient.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access files on a computer whilst it is in 'Sleep' or 'Hibernate' mode.

Sleep mode effectively saves all current activity to RAM, and turns nearly everything off to save power, but still allowing it to quickly resume what it was doing.

Hibernate is nearly the same as Sleep, but it saves everything to the hard-drive, allowing it to turn everything off, and resume it's operations in a timely manner.

Comment: Sorry, I realize my question was not clear. I meant to ask, "how do I reestablish that connection after powering up from hibernating or sleeping?" I edited the question to make that clear.